# Parsing through a QUERY PLAN to return specific results

Tags: postgresql, execute, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to create a function to estimate the number of rows in a given hypertable.

```
select * from items where id = 'Xa4511' and "timestamp" >= date_trunc('day', now());
```

```
Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on items    (cost=0.42..150.97 rows=76 width=160)
  Chunks excluded during startup: 75
  ->  Index Scan using _hyper_2_2128_chunk_items_id_timestamp_idx on _hyper_2_2128_chunk  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=136)
        Index Cond: (((id)::text = 'Xa4511'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('day'::text, now())))
```

I can get the 76 in `Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on items    (cost=0.42..150.97 rows=76 width=160)`

But with this specific table, would prefer to loop through each one of these scans:
`->  Index Scan using _hyper_2_2128_chunk_items_id_timestamp_idx on _hyper_2_2128_chunk  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=136)` and pull the rows for each since it's a bit more accurate. However, the query I'm using always returns null.

so for example:

```
Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on items (cost=0.29..4751.10 rows=51440 width=196)
  Chunks excluded during startup: 54
  ->  Index Scan using _hyper_5_2121_chunk_items_id_timestamp_idx on _hyper_5_2121_chunk  (cost=0.42..1722.80 rows=19017 width=196)
        Index Cond: (((id)::text = 'xb1a'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('month'::text, now())))
  ->  Index Scan using _hyper_5_2097_chunk_items_timestamp_idx on _hyper_5_2097_chunk  (cost=0.29..2944.74 rows=32369 width=196)
        Index Cond: ("timestamp" >= date_trunc('month'::text, now()))
        Filter: ((id)::text = 'xb1a'::text)
```

the above should return 51,386 (19017 + 32369)

My current function is below

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION count_estimate(query text) RETURNS integer AS $$
declare
  counter integer := 0;
  rec   record;
  rows  integer;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query loop
    counter := counter + 1;
    IF counter >= 1 THEN
        rows := substring(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
    end IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN rows;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Comment: You should be using `EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON)`, which is more machine-readable.

Comment: I switched to format json and get a nicely formatted version of explain in a single record, but am still unsure how to get the total rows using that.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387817 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743708

Answer (score 1):

For that, it is much easier to use the JSON format of `EXPLAIN`. The function to estimate the number of rows could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION estimate_rows(query text) RETURNS numeric
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   j json;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) ' || query
      INTO j;
   RETURN CAST(j -> 0 -> 'Plan' ->> 'Plan Rows' AS numeric);
END;$$;
```